# Proof of the existence of a solution on IVP with a given interval for $x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Prove that the solution $y(x)$ exists on the given interval for $x$:
$$y'=y^2 + \cos x^2$$
on $0\leq x\leq 1/2$ with $y(0)=0$.
I think that I have to use Picard's Theorem. But I don't know why I am given an interval for $x$. And the left bound of $x$ is the initial value. Any help?

Comment: Lipschitz continuity of $f(x,y)$ on which domain?

Comment: Is it $\cos(x^2)$ or $\cos^2(x)=(\cos x)^2$? What do you know and make of the bounds in the Picard.Lindelöf theorem? Can you use that $y'\le y^2+1$ and thus $y(x)\le\tan(x)$?

Comment: Hi. First of all thanks for the responses. It is cos(x^2). It doesn't give me a specific domain. The problem only asks for existence so we don't care about Lipschitz continuity. The thing is that this problem is very easy to solve because f(x,y) is continuous so a solution exists. What confuses me is why I am given a specific Interval for x. Yes I can use that y′≤y^2+1 and thus y(x)≤tan(x).

Answer (score 1):

The task asks if $[0,\frac12]$ is a subset of the domain of the (or a) maximal solution of the IVP. This is a non-trivial question as the solution will diverge to infinity in finite time as soon as it reaches a value larger than $1$, as $y'>y^2-1$ gives an exploding lower bound.

---

First variant, $y'\le y^2+1$ gives that, as long as the solution exists, $y(x)\le \tan(x)$. In the consequence, the solution remains bounded above for $x<\frac\pi2$. As long as $\cos(x^2)\ge 0$, that is, $x\le\sqrt{\frac\pi2}$, it is also clear that $y$ is increasing and thus positive. Both together give that, for instance, $[0,1]$ is a subset of the maximal domain.

---

Second variant, if you want to go by the Picard iteration, you first fix a rectangle $R$ via $|x|\le a$, $|y|\le b$. Then the right side function is bounded by $|f(x,y)|\le M=b^2+1$ on $R$. Solutions are guaranteed by this bound to stay inside this rectangle for $|x|\le h$ if $Mh\le b$. Next for the convergence one needs that $q=Lh<1$ for the contraction factor of the Picard iteration, where $L=2b$ is an $y$-Lipschitz constant. Both conditions can be satisfied if $h$ is chosen small enough. As the bounds do not depend on $a$, one can set $a=h$. With $b=1$ these conditions are satisfied for any $h<\frac12$, it follows that the solution exists at least on $[0,1]$, with a limit at $x=\frac12$ due to boundedness.

Comment: Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the unique solution of the IVP
$$
y'=1+y^2, \quad y(0)=0,
$$
is $y(x)=\tan x$, and its maximal interval is $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Next, define the Picard sequence $y_n(x)=\int_0^x \big(\cos^2t+y_{n-1}^2(t)\big)\,dt$ of
$$
y'=\cos^2(x)+y^2, \quad y(0)=0,
$$
and prove inductively that,
$$
0= y_0(x)\le y_1(x)\le \cdots\le y_n(x)\le y_{n+1}(x)\le \tan x, \quad x\in [0,\pi).
$$
Hence, $y_n$ converges to some $y(x)\le \tan x$, for $x\in [0,\pi/2)$.

Also, for $x\in [0,1/2]$, we have $½<\pi/6$, and hence $\tan(1/2)<\tan(\pi/6)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.
$$
0\le y_{n+1}(x)-y_n(x)=\int_0^x \big(y_n^2(t)-y_{n-1}^2(t)\big)\,dt
=\int_0^x \big(y_n(t)+y_{n-1}(t)\big)\big(y_n(t)-y_{n-1}(t)\big)\,dt
\\ \le 2\tan x \int_0^x \big(y_n(t)-y_{n-1}(t)\big)\,dt \le
\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\int_0^x \big(y_n(t)-y_{n-1}(t)\big)\,dt
$$
In particular, $y_1(x)-y_0(x)=\int_0^x \cos^2t\,dt \le x$,
$$
y_2(x)-y_1(x)\le \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\int_0^x \big(y_1(t)-y_0(t)\big)\,dt \le 
\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\int_0^x t\,dt \le \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\cdot \frac{x^2}{2} 
$$
$$
y_3(x)-y_2(x)\le \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\int_0^x \big(y_2(t)-y_1(t)\big)\,dt \le 
\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\int_0^x \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\cdot \frac{t^2}{2}\,dt \le \left(\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)^2\cdot \frac{x^3}{3!} 
$$
and inductively
$$
0 \le y_{n}(x)-y_{n-1}(x)\le  \left(\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)^{n-1}\cdot \frac{x^{n}}{n!} \le \frac{1}{n!} , \quad x\in [0,1/2],
$$
Hence $\{y_n(x)\}$ converges uniformly in $[0,1/2]$ ([Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test)) and the limit $y(x)$ satisfies
$$
y(x)=\int_0^x \big(\cos^2t+y^2(t)\big)\,dt, \quad x\in [0,1/2]
$$
and hence $y$ satisfies the IVP.

**Note.** The interval $[0,1/2]$ could be replaced by $[-a,a]$, for any $0<a<\pi/2$.

Comment: While the principle ideas should remain valid, your answer is to a slightly different ODE, it was confirmed that the square is for $\cos(x^2)$.